# skype main.db in the Android devices

Tags: android, skype

Is there any way to find a main.db in the Android devices? I copied all files in debug mode and I only found is some cached files (in com.skype.raider).

Android v. 4.3, Skype v. 4.9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need root..

/data/data/com.skype.raider